# Checking if stack allocation fails?

Tags: c, stack, c99, allocation

Is there a way to correct failed static allocation or program just fails with Segmentation or Bus Fault when run?

Post was inspired by how C99 allows crazy stuff like `char text[n];`

*EDIT*: Thanks. I now understand the part in bold is not a static alloc. So just to check, if something like `char text[1234];` fails would the possible recovery strategies be the same?

Comment: that's not static allocation. That's on the stack. If you think it could fail then use the heap.

Comment: That isn't static allocation.

Comment: Enclose code in `backticks`, not **double asterisks**.

Answer (score 3):

`char text[n]` allocates a variable-size array on the stack. It simply involves incrementing the stack pointer by `n`.

There is not much a userspace process can do if a stack overflow occurs - it's up to the operating system to either send a signal to the process and terminate it or resize the stack.

Comment: `libsigsegv` has a stack overflow handler for many platforns.

Comment: @Chris: way to go recommending more of the 1980s-style "portable by virtue of having a system-specific hack for every known system" sort of code... ;-)

Comment: @R.. - I didn't say it was _good_, just that it might be relevant. I wouldn't be using VLA's in the first place for this very reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably catch the signal(s) but there's not much else you can do. Of course, checking `n` before using it to make sure it has a sensible value would solve this instantly.

Comment: @ImJustALittleCatfish **Danger, Will Robinson!** Please don't trust signals as a good idea. Signals are *always* a bad idea (entire books can be written about how signals and async-signal-unsafety complicate programming).

Comment: Hmm there's a difference between "complicated" and "bad". But I can imagine why using signals THIS way would be cumbersome.

Comment: Lots of things "complicate" programming, but I'd argue that all Un*x server processes  should catch at least a couple of signals.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth Don't you just love non-standard `syscall` restarting rules ? Oh and mixing pthreads with signals: there's a fun afternoon. Oh and did I mention that time when some smarty-pants thought unmasking the signal turing its handling is a great idea ?

Comment: @cnicutar Don't care - want my specific server implementation  to re-read its config, or shut down in a semi-controlled way.  If some threads are screwed, so be it - they would be anyway.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth Signals have a time and place. Catching `SIGHUP` to re-read the conf is probably OK. Then again, in this age of awesome `IPC` mechanisms, why stick with signals ?

Comment: Because the users of our servers will insist on typing `kill XXXX` in their xterms? And because it is an industry standard.

Comment: What can you do in a signal handler if you catch a SIGSEGV generated by the system because of the memory allocation?  You can exit - that's safe.  You can't return from the signal handler in the ordinary way; you have not resolved the cause of the signal.  So, you're left with the possibility of a `siglongjmp()` if you previously did a `sigsetjmp()` to save a `sigjmpbuf` for later use.  Anything else is at best very platform specific, and probably not very effective.

Comment: If the stack overflow happens in a worker thread that can safely terminate, the signal handler could (running on an alternate stack setup by `sigaltstack`) just set a flag that it happened, and call `pthread_exit` (which is not async-signal-safe, so of course you must be sure no async-signal-unsafe function was interrupted).

Comment: @Jonathan Who was talking about SIGSEGV? I (at least) was talking about handling signals from users.

Comment: @Neil: OK - user signals are one thing (and SIGINT, SIGQUIT, SIGHUP, SIGTERM and SIGPIPE should at least be considered for handling). The main question was asking about what would happen if you run out of stack space, and a signal was mooted as a response, and I deemed that the signal would be SIGSEGV (not implausible; not necessarily correct), and pointed out that there is no sane way to return from a signal handler set to catch that signal except possibly via `siglongjmp()`, and even that is somewhat fraught.

Answer (score 1):

Never check for an error condition you don't know how to handle.

Seriously, what are you planning on doing?  There is only a small subset of function you are allowed to call from a signal handler (see `man 7 signal`), and printf and longjmp (longjmp is the only way I can think of to recover from such a problem) are not one of them.  If you are going to the trouble to re-exec the process, you might as well have a nanny to do that job and avoid the mess.

Note according to `man alloca` you don't actually get told that the "allocation" fails, you just get a SIGSEGV when you try to access the bad memory, and of course that might not happen in the text[] array at all, or perhaps not even in the function that allocates text[] at all.

While the above two paragraphs are based on Linux, the overarching theory is true for all platforms.

Use malloc and have clean handling.  Be sane.

[EDIT]

Actually there is one way to try and do this, and that is by computing the start of the stack (recording stack in main) and stack limit (hoping the OS doesn't run out of pages).  Then before you do the large stack allocation you can compute how close you are to the end.  Give yourself a generous wiggle-room and fail before you allocate.

Comment: `longjmp` from a signal handler *is valid* as long as you can ensure that no async-signal-unsafe function was running when the signal handler was invoked.

Comment: @R.: Exactly.  However, you rarely can know that.  Any SIGSEGV in his program for any reason would cause the issue.  But let us assume perfect programming and that no function BEFORE the large allocation would cause a problem.  You would have to ensure that nothing in the function that does the large allocation *and any function it calls* could call an unsafe function.  Though actually the perfect programmer text gave me an idea that this should be handled as a pre-crime.  Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a stack allocation rather than static. The failure mode is stack overflow. The most rational policy for stack overflow is to regard it as terminal.

Design your code so that it won't overflow the stack rather than trying to make it resilient to stack overflow.